# How to whereDate, whereMonth a variable?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to display the *total payments overall*, and *total payments for this month* using only one variable.

**Controller**

```
$payments = Payment::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

return view('subscribers.payments', compact(['payments']));
```

**View**

```
<label>Total payments</label>
<p>{{ $payments->sum('amount') }}</p>

<label>For this month</label>
<p>{{ $payments->whereMonth('created_at', now()->month)->sum('amount') }}</p>
```

Actually the *total payments overall* displayed. But the "for this month" it is not working and returns me an error below:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereMonth does not exist.

---

Someone could tell me where I went wrong? and proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't querying by month alone going to create a problem later when you have more than one year of data?  I would just use the start of the current month.

```php
<p>{{ $payments->where('created_at', '>=', now()->startOfMonth())->sum('amount') }}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Sir. One last quesiton, what is the difference of `now()->startOfMonth()` and `now()->month`, just curious?

Comment: `now()->startOfMonth()` is a Carbon instance for the earliest date in the current month (2019-09-01 00:00:00).  `now()->month` is an integer representation of the current month (9).

Comment: ahh that is why it can't compare `created_at` directly because it's an integer thanks well-explained

Answer (score 2):

so `whereMonth` is unfortunately only available with the query builder. You could `filter` the items after they've been retrieved:

```
$payments->filter(function ($payment) {
    return $payment->created_at->month == now()->month;
})->sum('amount')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Sir. It returns me an error `Object of class Illuminate\Support\Carbon could not be converted to int`

Comment: Perhaps try `created_at->month`

Comment: It's working sir thanks. But I will choose the less coding.